# SQL: How to convert date: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.sssss to : yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, date, format

I am trying use CAST and CONVERT, but I didn't get it right.

```
convert(nvarchar, my_date, 121);
```

Exemple:

```
convert(nvarchar,my_date,121) as new_date_format;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong functions. You need to use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert that string into a datetime type and then use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format that in the new desired format:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_date, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s.%f"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the DATE_FORMAT function, it will accept a string as the input date and lets you specify the exact output format:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format